# lubridate error message 'incompatible method's when trying date arithmetic

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm trying to learn lubridate. The lubridate documentation shows:

```
date <- ceiling_date(date, "month") - days(1)
[1] "2010-05-31 UTC
```

for date arithmetic. But if I try

```
mytoday <- now()
first_of_month <- floor_date(mytoday, "month")
first_of_month_last_year <- first_of_month - years(1)
```

to use date arithmetic to get the first of the month a year earlier I get an error message

```
Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("-.POSIXt", "Ops.ordered") for "-"
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: It works fine with lubridate 1.3.0.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same problem.

In my case it was that I had two date/time related packages installed (chron and lubridate), which appears to conflict with each other to some degree.

I solved this by removing chron as I wasn't really using it.

If you are using multiple date/time related packages, I would suggest removing these packages, then reinstalling them, with lubridate last. However, you may run into other conflicts.

Hope this helps.